# How to fix internal link issues when publishing a Docusaurus site on GitLab pages

Tags: hyperlink, gitlab-pages, docusaurus

In my Docusaurus project my internal links work on my local environment, but when I push to GitLab they no longer work. Instead of replacing the original doc title with the new one it adds it to the url at the end ('https://username.io/test-site/docs/overview/add-a-category.html'). I looked over my config file, but I do not understand why this is happening.

I tried updating the id in the front matter for the page, and making sure it matches the id in the sidebars.json file. I have also added customDocsPath and set it to 'docs/' in the config file, though that is supposed to be the default.

```
---
id: "process-designer-overview"
title: "Process Designer Overview"
sidebar_label: "Overview"
---
# Process Designer

The Process Designer is a collaborative business process modeling and 
design workspace for the business processes, scenarios, roles and tasks 
that make up governed data processes.

Use the Process Designer to:

 - [Add a Category](add-a-category.html)
 - [Add a Process or Scenario](Add%20a%20Process%20or%20Scenario.html)
 - [Edit a Process or Scenario](Edit%20a%20Process%20or%20Scenario.html)
```

I updated the add a category link in parenthesis to an md extension, but that broke the link on my local and it still didn't work on GitLab. I would expect that when a user clicks on the link it would replace the doc title in the url with the new doc title ('https://username.gitlab.io/docs/add-a-category.html') but instead it just tacks it on to the end ('https://username.gitlab.io/docs/process-designer-overview/add-a-category.html') and so the link is broken as that is not where the doc is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues with my links. First, I converted these files from html to markdown using Pandoc and did not add front matter - relying instead on the file name to connect my files to the sidebars. This was fine, except almost all of the file names had spaces in them, which you can see in my code example above. This was causing real issues, so I found a Bash script to replace all of the spaces in my file names with underscores, but now all of my links were broken. I updated all of the links in my files with a search and replace in my code editor, replacing "%20" with "_". I also needed to replace the ".html" extension with ".md" or my project would no longer work locally. Again, I did this with a search and replace in my code editor.

Finally, I ended up adding the front matter because otherwise my sidebar titles were all covered in underscores. Since I was working with 90 files, I didn't want to do this manually. I looked for a while and found a [great gist by thebearJew](https://gist.github.com/thebearjew/79f5f572baa8dc8e6d492a282c7d4fc9) and adjusted it so that it would take the file name and add it as the id, and the first heading and add it as the title and sidebar_label, since as it happens that works for our project. Here is the Bash script I found online to convert the spaces in my file names to underscores if interested:

```
find $1 -name "* *.md" -type f -print0 | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

Here is the script I ended up with if anyone else has a similar setup and doesn't want to update a huge amount of files with front matter:

```
# Given a file path as an argument
# 1. get the file name
# 2. prepend template string to the top of the source file
# 3. resave original source file

# command: find . -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 -I file ./prepend.sh file

filepath="$1"
file_name=$("basename" -a "$filepath")

# Getting the file name (title)
md='.md'
title=${file_name%$md}
heading=$(grep -r "^# \b" ~/Documents/docs/$title.md)
heading1=${heading#*\#}

# Prepend front-matter to files
TEMPLATE="---
id: $title
title: $heading1
sidebar_label: $heading1
---
"
echo "$TEMPLATE" | cat - "$filepath" > temp && mv temp "$filepath"
```